# TFS 2013 Disabled AD Users Appearing

Tags: tfs, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got an issue where users that are disabled in Active Directory are still appearing in a Team Project Collection in Team Foundation Server 2013. This is a problem because any projects that are within the collection have these users inherited and are visible when assigning work items, etc.

These users in the screenshot below are all disabled and none of which are a part of any group or groups on TFS.
Specifically these users:

- Kumar
- Carl
- Mishra
- Bertram
- Shah
- Rajendran
- Arora

It would also be nice to hide these users:

- Network Service
- Sharepoint account
- Local Server Account (******-DEV1$)

[image: Disabled Users Appearing in TFS 2013]

I have tried the following:

- Removing [Built-In]\Administrators group as per instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15640409/559988
- Clearing the TFS data cache and restarting IIS as per instructions here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31487b77-8a1a-4b1f-8cdb-8f3528a3a389/tfs-2013-user-management
- Verified the users are disabled in Active Directory
- Verified the disabled users are not apart of any groups in Active Directory
- Verified Active Directory sync is working (added a new user and it appeared just fine).

Has anyone else had this issue with disabled users appearing in TFS 2013 or know how to resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is correct. The disabled user in Active Directory will still appear in TFS. Since these users are imported from AD, and belong windows group, so you can't delete these from security page. TFS server will automatically sync from the AD.

You may need to manually **delete** the users instead of disable the users in Active Directory .

---

Update

You can't hide the user in security. If you are get annoyed with these users when assigning work items. You can filter the user which you want to display in work item drop list. Please see my answer in this question: [TFS-2015 limiting user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108621/tfs-2015-limiting-user-list/33122403#33122403) for detailed step.

Comment: Is there any way to hide/filter the users instead of removing them? Our long-standing policy has been to disable AD users instead of remove them. Also -- do you know if there is any Microsoft documentation to substantiate your knowledge?

Comment: Sorry,I can't found any related documentation in MSDN. However, I have tested in my local environment early. And also there is no way to hide the users in TFS.  If you are get annoyed with these users when  assigning work items. You can filter the user which you want display in work item drop list. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks again for your response. So I need to create custom Work Item Templates for all of my work item types to be able to do the filtering? 
Additionally, I'll see if I can test out the AD user deletion theory in our environment.

Comment: I deleted one of the user accounts from Active Directory, then I cleared the TFS cache and restarted IIS. However, the user account is still appearing in the list on TFS. Any ideas? Or do you know how long it will take to potentially flush out any cache Active Directory may have?

Comment: Just as you suspect, Changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly (by default every hour). However, cleared TFS cache and restarted IIS will not work. You can delete and re-add the security group in TFS, this will trigger a **identity synchronization**.  More info from this link: http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/

Comment: Patrick, I ran the TfsSyncIdentities.exe (a couple times) and it synced with AD. However, the user still persists as shown in the original screenshot despite being deleted from AD. The user doesn't exist in AD, Exchange, or Lync. Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure you have delete all groups in TFS?  TfsSecurity.exe /server:http://xx:8080/tfs /im n:tfstrain \username   run this command will return the group of user, <A>stand for the TFS group <G>stand for the windows user group

Comment: I ran the command you have to show the groups a user belongs to, and the user doesn't belong to any TFS groups. I have also triple checked the user is not in Active Directory. For comparison I ran the command on my user account and it shows I'm apart of 84 groups. Here's a screenshot to show the results: http://i.imgur.com/UPx85fM.png
That user data has to be cached somewhere on TFS because we have searched high and low and cannot find it on AD. Any ideas?

Comment: Patrick, I have also validated via EventViewer that the TFS-AD Identity Synchronization is occurring hourly without issue or errors. Hopefully you have a solution for this :)

Comment: If that's the case, please use the `/imx` instead of `/im` this will display information about the identities that compose the expanded membership of a specified group. And please also use this tool TFS Sidekicks  http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ This tool will also list the user whether belong to any TFS groups.

Comment: If both of above show the user doesn't belong to any TFS group. And you can still see the user in the security page. Then it may be a bug.

Comment: I used the /imx switch on tfssecurity and the user belongs to two "valid users groups" but I can't see a way to remove them. 
http://i.imgur.com/hiAYYM4.png How can I remove the users from those groups?

Comment: Please use `tfssecurity  /g-` command to remove a user or a user group from an existing group. A example: `tfssecurity /g- groupIdentity memberIdentity  [/collection:CollectionURL]`  for memberIdentity use `n:[user ID]]`. More detail for you reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd

Comment: I tried that and received the following: **Error: TF50618: The Team Foundation Valid Users group cannot be modified directly.**
Then I modified your script to also try removing the user from `[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Valid` users by using the `/server` switch instead of `/collection`. This returned the same error as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything in **Patrick's post above** I am unable to resolve this issue.

This issue also remains unresolved in a similar post here: [How do I remove a user from tfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681810/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-tfs?noredirect=1#comment57644529_23681810)

The only way I was able to **partially-resolve** this was by upgrading from TFS 2013 to TFS 2015. The users still appear in the Project Collection users group, but no longer appear in the Team Project as options for work items, etc.
It's unclear why this is the way it is.