# Team Foundation server 2015 - Delete old users

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS server that has been moved between multiple physical servers and upgraded throughout versions 2005 -> 2015 during the past 10 years. It was working under a domain controller, but now its standing alone. When managing security and working with work items, it become like a mess. Too many old users are showing, some of them are duplicated with old names. However, we are dealing with windows users, so many of these users doesn't exists anymore. TFS web portal is showing a list of all existing users, but it doesn't offer delete option.

1. How can I delete them (old users)?
2. Is it the right procedure to follow (I
   believe it won't be worst, as when I open work item owned by old
   user, TFS shows the old name, but give a warning that this user
   doesn't exists anymore)

Comment: you don't really want to delete old users. Just because Bob doesn't work for the company any more, there is still value in knowing that Bob changed that method in 2007, or introduced that backdoor in 2014.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But let's assume that Bob is still working, but now I ended up having 3 Bobs each was defined as a windows user on a physical machine during the upgrade live time. Maybe a command that merge all old Bobs can solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I cannot confirm this solution will work.

From I could gather on Internet you need to delete user from all groups/collection they belonged to and then delete their windows account.

[Overall](http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2009/12/tfs-windows-user-delete.html)

[Delete from groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681810/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-tfs)

[Link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/) to kick off TFS active sync.

Another solution could be using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/12/15/announcing-team-foundation-server-administration-tool/) software if it works with tfs 2015 or getting only important part of its source code from [here](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Comment: This has helped partially. In short, when removing the usage of old users/groups the TFS won't show them anymore in the "Group membership area". However, these old objects still shows in work items, but not in the "Team Foundation Server Administration Tool"! Now there are two things to try:
1- Remove the old users assignments from all old work items
2- Wait until TFS sync users list. 
I'll try both and post the results soon

Comment: if you remove old work items it should clear them out within a week or so.

Comment: I'm still free to restart the server or maybe the TFS instance. Does this help in removing them immediately? What is the actual trigger for this sync operation?

Comment: I added a link to website I saw, but users cannot be in any groups, have any work items.