# remove user from TFS completely

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

[image]I have a user which needs to be removed from TFS all together. I have removed him from the respective projects and he is not able to see the projects but he is still able to access TFS url. I want to remove him so that he cannot even access the URL.
I am using TFS 2015 Update 2.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I am having a similar issue user has been removed from groups and ad groups and yet they still appear in TFS.

Answer (score 1):

Changes you make to local or Active Directory groups **do not get reflected in TFS immediately**. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly.

You can **re-add the security group** in TFS, this will trigger a identity
   synchronization. More ways you can find in this blog: [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)

Some other related articles may help you:

- [A case study on TFS identity replication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emmamou/2009/03/13/a-case-study-on-tfs-identity-replication/)
- [Identity Synchronization in Team Foundation Server 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vasu_sankaran/2010/06/07/identity-synchronization-in-team-foundation-server-2010/)

Comment: thanks for the info. I am using TFS 2015 and not comfortable in manipulating the database. What is the Sync job that needs does the cleanup, can it be triggered manually.

Comment: Did you move that user in your all the TFS groups?  There is a periodic clean-up job that is executed that removes people from the global groups. Even though the threads are talking about TFS2010, it's also suitable for TFS2015. You can also check this similar question  in SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681810/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-tfs

Comment: i have followed the link already and removed the user from every group, and it has been around 4 to 5 days, but user still can access the URL. Wanted to execute the cleanup job manually.

Comment: A way should do the trick, remove that user in local domain group and re-add it again.

Comment: If it's still not work also take a look at this link from MSDN:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx  which using the *JobService* *webservice*, through that you can queue the identity synchronization job.

Comment: i followed the link and executed the powershell which executed the identity sync job but, the user still has permission or i can see the user when do a search. Anything that i am missing?

Comment: Could you use the  the imx command to display information about the identities that compose the expanded membership https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#imx You can update the result in your question.

Comment: i executed the command and the output says :
Member of 2 group(s):
e [A] [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Valid Users
e [A] [CollectionName]\Project Collection Valid Users

Comment: Have told you all methods which I can think of. Also try to restart the “Team Foundation Server Background  Job Agent” service after executed the identity sync job.

Comment: That's i have not done. Since it will take a downtime will do it in few days. Will post and update.

Comment: After some test, I found a way works for me. Usually we will add a windows group in TFS group. Now you just need to delete the windows group and readd  the group to TFS again. This action will trigger TFS sync take effect immediately.

Comment: i tried that, but we do not add users using AD group. I found a clue though, the user can still view the vNext build Agent queue. I guess it means that the user has some permission added somewhere in the vNext permissions. Please help.

Comment: @Angshuman For this, you can try to use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) . For example: `tf permission /user:userID /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`  which will return the modified permission for that user under the collection path. Also work with server path.

Comment: Hi Patrick, i am still not able to solve the issue. I have one more information for you, the user was added using the command: TFSSecurity.exe\" /g+ \"[$project]\\$role\" n:VISA\\$username /collection:\. Hope this can help you find some clue. Appreciate your help all along.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the user is added to a security group on the collection or server level.

**Collection level**
Browse to the settings page for the collection http://[YourServer]:8080/tfs/[YourCollection]/_admin/_securi‌​ty. From here you can search for the user and see what AD/TFS groups she/he is a member of.

**Application level**
Remote to your TFS App-tier server and launch Team Foundation Server Administration Console. Under the Application Tier node, you can inspect the Group Membership from top and down. I haven't found an easy way to browse for a particular user, so I guess that browsing through each group recursively is the only option.

Remember that the user can both be 'hidden' somewhere in a TFS or AD group e.g. *[YourProject]\Readers* or *YourDomain\Domain Users*

Comment: in the above the user is not member of any group or identity as mentioned in the question, i had removed him from all places.

Comment: Have you checked both TFS groups and AD groups? You can usually find that if you go to the admin page linked above and search for the user.

Comment: TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Valid Users e [A] [CollectionName]\Project Collection Valid Users
the user exist in these two

Comment: Hmm, that sounds strange. It should not be possible to add individual users to these groups. The add button is simply grayed out. Can you remove the membership by navigating to http://[YourServer]:8080/tfs/[YourCollection]/_admin/_securi‌​ty click the Users headline, search for the specific user, select 'Member of' and clicking the Remove text link to the right of the group?

Comment: The user is not a member of any grp. But still a member of the two groups mentioned above

Comment: @Angshuman It is not that I don't beleve you, but could you provide a screenshot from the users 'Member of' section?

Comment: I have added the image. Please check.

Comment: Oki, that looks very clean! Do you only have one collection or is it the same result in the other collections? Have you checked the Group Membership on the Application Tier in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console on you TFS App Tier server?

Comment: i checked all the collections, The user cannot access any other collection and the search results in no user found. I found a clue though, the user can still view the vNext build Agent queue. I guess it means that the user has some permission added somewhere in the vNext permissions. Please help.

Comment: Maybe the user still have a role on a vNext agent. These roles can be set here: http://YourServer:8080/tfs/YourCollection/_admin/_AgentQueue?_a=roles